# Angular Input Placeholder on the top

Tags: html, css, angular

I am new in Angular and I have to create an input field like that:

[image]

Everything is ok besides the Vorname placeholder on the top.
How can I put it there?

I am using Angular Materials.

```
<div class='grid-container-left'>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <input matInput placeholder={{angeforderteVerfueger.request.vorname}} readonly>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance!

---

---

**Answer:**

The below provided solutions works, just have to add floatLabel value with always.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
            <mat-label>Vorname</mat-label>
            <input matInput [placeholder]="angeforderteVerfueger.request.vorname" readonly>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a label before your input:

```html
<mat-label>Vorname</mat-label>
```

Comment: thanks, but in this case the placeholder text (Iris) is gonna be replaced with the mat-label text

Comment: You can make a variable that containing the placeholder and when focus in input change the placeholder to "Vorname" for example and you won't need `mat-label` any more. Hope that helps

Comment: I do not really get what you mean. Then I would not show both of my text at the same time, or am I wrong? My input field is disabled an containing a predefined data and the Vorname should define this type of predefined data. So I need them both to present.

Comment: Did you check the official Angular Material [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#input-overview) ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is binding a property using string interpolation which is the wrong syntax. Try this

```
    <div class='grid-container-left'>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Vorname</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [placeholder]="angeforderteVerfueger.request.vorname" readonly>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working, but only when I click in the input field, then it shows the mat-label text. I wish this input field to be readonly, only to show the data inserted for after-check, so the text should always be visible. How can I mark my input as clicked in a readyonly state?

Comment: UPDATE: I have managed to set a focus on the field, but it only works when it is not readonly.